# Interpretation of Abelian Extension?

Tags: galois-theory, galois-extensions

My question is if I am understanding the definition of Abelian Extension correctly because the book I am reviewing is not explicit in its definition. For some finite extension of a field $F$ by $\omega$, the text says that an extension $F(\omega)$ is abelian if every automorphism fixing $F$ is abelian on composition with another automorphism fixing $F$.

I am interpreting this to mean that the Galois group $Gal(F(\omega):F)$ is abelian. To I have the correct idea, or am I missing an important detail?

Found an explicit definition from Wikipedia
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abelian

Comment: I think that it is usually implied that an abelian extension is automatically also Galois. Equivalently $|Gal(F(\omega):F)|=[F(\omega):F]$. Otherwise, for example, $\Bbb{Q}(\root3\of2)/\Bbb{Q}$ would qualify simply because the group of automorphisms is trivial. Caveat: there is some variation in the definitions and notations between books. Some authors only use the notation $Gal(L:K)$ when $L/K$ is a Galois extension. Others use it to simply denote the group of automorphisms.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen As in abelian extension always applies to the Galois group?